# DocuSign API: Changing the filename when signing from a template

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign API via VisualStudio, I create and send an Envelope out to customers based on a Template on my DocuSign account which contains a list of the recipients and a standard pdf document.
I specify the TemplateRoles and the TemplateId using the EnvelopeDefinition object then create the Envelope. The pdf document returned when everything is signed will have the same name as the pdf on the Template document.

What I need to do is change the name of this document for each Envelope/customer. Ideally I could change the document name to that of the customer to make it easier to store and find, instead of getting a lot of different docs back with one generic name.

Is it at all possible to change the name of the finished document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about changing the name of the document.

But you can change the subject of the envelope when you create the envelope. And it is the subject of the envelope that you see in the DocuSign web tool.

You can also set an envelope custom property and later search for envelopes with that property. Using this technique, you could easily bring up all envelopes related to a particular customer (probably best to store your customer_id as an envelope custom property in this case).

Comment: We do set the Subject field but the issue itself is that the docs are passed on and it then becomes difficult to reference those docs. Users could rename them on a per-doc basis but this isn't reliable. Ideally the finished document would have a unique name.

Comment: The authoritative copy of the finished document lives in the DocuSIgn system. The answer is to not download it, just display it from DocuSign as needed. Or download into an organized archive system that is managed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but it works.

You can create a dummy cc recipient and their name can be anything (their email address can be random letters). Set up your template with the merge fields to include in the message subject (this also automatically edits the envelope name). Using this guide:

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-template-merge-fields

Then when you create your envelope from the template, fill in the dummy name with whatever text you want to be added to the envelope name.